# Error with External Content Type List: "Unable to display this web part"

Tags: 2010, bcs, external-content-type, external-list

I have deployed an external content type to my local Sharepoint 2010 Server using a Visual Studio solution. The deployment appears to work. I can view the details of the content part in the central administration pages.

I have created a list using this content type but if try to view it, I get the following error:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

If I actually try to view the list within SharePoint Designer, I get an error message complaining about a Soap Exception.

I've looked at other places on the internet that talk about this error, and most of them suggest it is an issue with throttling the connection. However, I am able to step into the `ReadList()` method on my "Service" class for the external content type, and it's only returning 24 items.

Things that I've tried so far:

- Retracting and redeploying the solution.
- Increasing the "throttle limit" to a larger number.
- Rebooting the server.

This is the log. I replaced the correllation id with (cid) to get the message body under 30000 characters.

```
06/29/2012 09:08:37.85  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:e455d5b8-8852-44ae-8326-20548325c427'  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.85  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.85  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.85  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5g    Medium      Calling GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod for Method with Id 143    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.85  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetFilterDescriptorsForMethodWithCount   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.85  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod' in BdcServiceApplication. (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.85  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.918273132479128   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.87  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetLobSystemInstancesForLobSystem' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:fd836e4a-38c9-4118-a131-4c63a150786c'  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.87  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.87  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetLobSystemInstancesForLobSystem' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.87  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5v    Medium      Calling GetLobSystemInstancesForLobSystem for System with Id 111    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.87  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetSystemInstancesForSystemWithCount (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.87  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetLobSystemInstancesForLobSystem' in BdcServiceApplication. (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.87  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.815187405103163   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.88  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetAllProperties' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:1c6e98c8-a2e8-455e-9823-c2d7702d9f50'   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.88  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.88  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetAllProperties' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.88  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5x    Medium      Calling GetAllProperties for object with Id 147 (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.88  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetPropertiesForMetadataObject   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.88  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetAllProperties' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.88  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.817701691136723   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.89  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetParametersForMethod' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:b2bc410a-525b-4fc4-82df-4e3a62899716' (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.89  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.89  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetParametersForMethod' in BdcServiceApplication. (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.89  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f63    Medium      Calling GetParametersForMethod for Method with Id 143   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.89  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetParametersForMethodWithCount  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.89  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetParametersForMethod' in BdcServiceApplication.    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.89  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.847593758424604   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.90  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetAllProperties' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:339484a2-1345-4358-9053-8214be332072'   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.90  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.90  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetAllProperties' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.90  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5x    Medium      Calling GetAllProperties for object with Id 112 (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.90  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetPropertiesForMetadataObject   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.90  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetAllProperties' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.90  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.888101700076406   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetAccessControlEntries' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:ff1c7234-819e-4c45-bc92-69a788fa20a9'    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetAccessControlEntries' in BdcServiceApplication.    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5y    Medium      Calling GetMetadataObjectById with Id 147   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetMethodInstanceById    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetAccessControlEntriesForMetadataObject (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f33    Verbose     Reading ACEs from Database  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f34    Verbose     Constructing SharePoint Foundation ACE with Identity 'c:0(.s|true' and Rights 'Execute' (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f34    Verbose     Constructing SharePoint Foundation ACE with Identity 'i:0#.w|treehouse\developer' and Rights 'Execute, Edit, SetPermissions, SelectableInClients'   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetAccessControlEntries' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.91  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=1.23591126805222    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.93  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetAllProperties' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:b8cdc2a9-e76a-4f5b-b23a-86df0f67d82d'   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.93  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.93  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetAllProperties' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.93  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5x    Medium      Calling GetAllProperties for object with Id 134 (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.93  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetPropertiesForMetadataObject   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.93  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetAllProperties' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.93  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=1.04957473645393    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.94  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:4adc8f24-8aa2-45a1-a237-0e9f4854fa39'  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.94  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.94  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.94  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5g    Medium      Calling GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod for Method with Id 143    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.94  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetFilterDescriptorsForMethodWithCount   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.94  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetFilterDescriptorsForMethod' in BdcServiceApplication. (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.94  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.704000089396837   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.95  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetEntitiesForSystem' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:343721be-2016-4bc6-a5de-6532fdde8d47'   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.95  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.95  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetEntitiesForSystem' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.95  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetEntitiesForSystemWithCount    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.95  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetEntitiesForSystem' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.95  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.728025489273078   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetServiceApplicationId' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:c3f0b319-3bdd-4811-a7e7-15d76e22ff4a'    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetServiceApplicationId' in BdcServiceApplication.    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetServiceApplicationId' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.209803201244851   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetServiceApplicationId' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:5e70342f-05fe-425c-8a9e-676d6a8b7887'    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetServiceApplicationId' in BdcServiceApplication.    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetServiceApplicationId' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:37.96  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x101C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.455085772074384   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:41.69  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/b7554e1c26914c7b995f090317cb23bd/MetadataWebService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/taxonomy/soap/IDataAccessReadOnly/GetChanges' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:e49a666e-46d3-4971-a05e-94c02ab1a130'  3b90d8f1-1031-40ca-b1f3-bb407556127c
06/29/2012 09:08:41.69  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    3b90d8f1-1031-40ca-b1f3-bb407556127c
06/29/2012 09:08:41.69  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc5    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' starting. 3b90d8f1-1031-40ca-b1f3-bb407556127c
06/29/2012 09:08:41.69  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Server               Taxonomy                        fuc6    Medium      MetadataWebServiceApplication.GetChanges called on 'Managed Metadata Service' completed.    3b90d8f1-1031-40ca-b1f3-bb407556127c
06/29/2012 09:08:41.69  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=1.76810181182245    3b90d8f1-1031-40ca-b1f3-bb407556127c
06/29/2012 09:08:44.83  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetAllLocalizedNames' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:bdf257e5-6366-4bc7-83ee-b4b8fe385c2f'   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.83  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.83  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetAllLocalizedNames' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.83  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5w    Medium      Calling GetAllLocalizedNames for object with Id 112 (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetAllLocalizedNamesForMetadataObjectWithCount   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetAllLocalizedNames' in BdcServiceApplication.  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x055C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.850946139802684   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x0CFC  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium      WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://developer.treehouse.local:32843/c7771f1529d34a6db837da62c320e284/bdcservice.svc/http' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://www.microsoft.com/Office/2009/BusinessDataCatalog/BusinessDataCatalogSharedService/GetIdentifiersForEntity' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:54bd432d-12d9-4ec6-8f9a-89785f85778d'    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x0CFC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation)    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x0CFC  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0qk    Verbose     Entering Bdc 'GetIdentifiersForEntity' in BdcServiceApplication.    (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x0CFC  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   9f5h    Medium      Calling GetIdentifiersForEntity for Entity with Id 134  (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x0CFC  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   fbv2    Verbose     Bdc Completed: proc_ar_GetIdentifiersForEntityWithCount (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x0CFC  Business Connectivity Services  Business Data                   f0ql    Verbose     Completed Bdc 'GetIdentifiersForEntity' in BdcServiceApplication.   (cid)
06/29/2012 09:08:44.84  w3wp.exe (0x1234)                           0x0CFC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0.707352470774917   (cid)
```

I have the logging for BCS set to the highest level, and yet nothing here seems to suggest an error.

Comment: FYI: despite your efforts, it still got flagged by the system as excessively long.

Comment: If it's too long, then the system shouldn't set such a high character limit? I thought it better to paste the log here than put it on something like pastebin because pastebin links a) a lot of potential readers won't click on, b) erode, and link rot is bad in the SE mindset, no?

Comment: @SPDoctor: I could shave some more characters off it, but as it versions the questions, any changes I made would probably just increase the amount of data stored? So not sure it's worthwhile. The character limit was 30k, question originally sat at 30.5, now it's at less than 27.

Comment: I think you have done all you can for the time being. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are many things that can cause this error, as it is a generic error message coming from the List Web Part rather than from BCC service it's annoyingly vague. I'm posting this here in the hopes that it will help someone else and save them from two days of banging their head against a wall.

For my situation, I tracked it down to me not "marking" the identifiers in the return type `<TypeDescriptor>` elements, like so...

Before:

```
<TypeDescriptors>
  <TypeDescriptor Name="TCU" TypeName="Model.TCU, Model" IsCollection="false">
    <TypeDescriptors>
      <TypeDescriptor Name="Code" TypeName="System.String" />
      <TypeDescriptor Name="Title" TypeName="System.String" />
      <TypeDescriptor Name="Type" TypeName="System.String" />
    </TypeDescriptors>
</TypeDescriptor>
```

After:

```
<TypeDescriptors>
  <TypeDescriptor Name="TCU" TypeName="Model.TCU, Model" IsCollection="false">
    <TypeDescriptors>
      <TypeDescriptor Name="Code" TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="Code" />
      <TypeDescriptor Name="Title" TypeName="System.String" />
      <TypeDescriptor Name="Type" TypeName="System.String" />
    </TypeDescriptors>
</TypeDescriptor>
```

Keeping in mind that you'll probably have this sort of thing at least twice (in your `ReadItem` and `ReadList` methods XML) as the BDCM doesn't seem to allow for any sort of templating that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem these days and found the solution in my case ! I'm posting this hoping that it would help.

**Context:**

Sharepoint 2013 Online. External data in SQLSERVER 2012.

**Scenario:**

- via SPD, I've created an external content type, choosing SQL server for the data source.
- I've created an external list from this ECT.

**Problem:**

In my site, when I try to show my list, I get the message:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

**Solution:**

In SPD --> External content types, I've modified my ECT connection properties and deleted the port from the server.

Hope it helps !